# maven parent artifactId not updating in IntelliJ project view and File - open recent

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have renamed the parent module in my maven project by changing its artifactId. I also updated all parent-artifactIds in the child modules accordingly. My problem is that even though i rebuilt the maven project (clean install, which worked) and reimported all Maven projects and restarted IntelliJ, the old artifactId is still displayed in the project view.

Have I missed something in order for IntelliJ to update the name? How can I fix the problem?

edit:

After following the instructions in the link of CrazyCoder, the new name is displayed correctly in the project view. I will write an answer to describe what I have done.

But I have noticed another problem now: In File -> Open recent the old artifactId is still displayed. I have not found where I can access what is displayed in this menu to rename it. The issue is resolvable by cloning the repository with git again. Is there also a way to fix this in IntelliJ?

Comment: It's a very old known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-26914.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very long known issue and can be resolved following these steps:

1. Change the artifactId in your poms wherever it is necessary
2. Run Clean-Install on your project to be sure everything is still working
3. Right Click on the project -> refactor -> rename or Shift-F6 and change the module name to match the new artifactId
4. The .iml file should be updated as well now. It might be that your IDE is confused now. Go to File and click Invalidate Cache/Restart

IntelliJ should now be displaying the correct name in the project view. According to my sources it could be necessary to update the names of the directories manually, which would be necessary between step 2 and 3. I did not have to do this, but still wanted to mention it if someone runs into that problem.

Another issue is that in Open Recent the old artifactId is still displayed. This is solvable by cloning the repository with git again. Unfortunately I have not found a way to do this in IntelliJ.